# On a VB form why are graphics disappearing when the form is first displayed?

Tags: vb.net, graphics

I have a form which displays graphs of various kinds, taken from sales data from a database.
These graphs are drawn on panels on the form but I have had a very recent issue. Up until recently, the form displayed the graphs when it was displayed but now the graphs appear then disappear and I cannot figure out why.

Here is a link to a Vimeo video showing the behaviour: https://vimeo.com/575969787

When the form is loaded a procedure is called in the Form_Shown event which draws the graphs - for ease of understanding I have restricted this to one graph only.

```
 Private Sub FormDashboard_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'Once form is initialised and shown run all the reports
        RunReports(True)
    End Sub

  Private Sub RunReports(All As Boolean)
        'Display these reports
        DrawDepartment(PanelFood, TableDepartment)
        'DrawDepartment(PanelWine, TableDepartment)
        'DrawDivision(PanelDivision, TableDepartment)
        'DrawCLA(PanelCLA, TableCLA)
        ''If all = true then also display MAT
        'If (All = True) Then
        '    DrawMAT(PanelMAT, TableMAT)
        'End If
    End Sub



Public Shared Sub DrawDepartment(TargetPanel As Panel, TableGraph As DataTable)

        'Graphics object
        Dim Dep_Graph As Graphics = TargetPanel.CreateGraphics
        Dim Offset As Integer = 45
        Dim DepName As String = ""

        'Graph area
        With TargetPanel
            GraphHeight = .Height - (Offset + Gap)
            GraphWidth = .Width - (2 * Gap)
            GraphXOrigin = Gap
            GraphYOrigin = (Offset + Gap)
        End With

        Dim Filter As String = "" 'Filter used for querying the data table
        Dim FoundMax() As DataRow 'A data row generated by a filter
        Dim FoundRows() As DataRow 'A data row generated by a filter

        'The data table has a max value for food sales in the given period
        If (TargetPanel.Name.Contains("Food")) Then
            Filter = "Department LIKE 'F%' OR Department LIKE 'S%'"
        Else
            Filter = "Department  LIKE 'W%'"
        End If

        Select Case Report
            Case ReportMode.Day
                TableGraph.DefaultView.Sort = "Day DESC"
                FoundMax = TableGraph.Select(Filter)
                MaxDataValue = FoundMax(0).Item("Day")

            Case ReportMode.Week
                TableGraph.DefaultView.Sort = "Week DESC"
                FoundMax = TableGraph.Select(Filter)
                MaxDataValue = FoundMax(0).Item("Week")

            Case ReportMode.Month
                TableGraph.DefaultView.Sort = "Month DESC"
                FoundMax = TableGraph.Select(Filter)
                MaxDataValue = FoundMax(0).Item("Month")

            Case ReportMode.Year
                TableGraph.DefaultView.Sort = "Year DESC"
                FoundMax = TableGraph.Select(Filter)
                MaxDataValue = FoundMax(0).Item("Year")

        End Select

        TableGraph.DefaultView.Sort = "Department"

        'Select only the food department values
        If (TargetPanel.Name.Contains("Food")) Then
            Filter = "Department LIKE 'F%' OR Department LIKE 'S%'"
        Else
            Filter = "Department LIKE 'W%'"
        End If
        FoundRows = TableGraph.Select(Filter)

        'Calculate the width of each column
        Dim NumberOfColumns As Integer = (FoundRows.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
        ColWidth = (GraphWidth - ((NumberOfColumns) * Gap)) / NumberOfColumns

        'Using the graphics object draw the columns
        With Dep_Graph
            MessageBox.Show("Clearing graph area")
            'Using the FoundMax data row extract the Day max value
            ClearGraph(TargetPanel)

            For Counter As Integer = 0 To FoundRows.GetUpperBound(0)
                Select Case Report
                    Case ReportMode.Day
                        DataValue = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Day")
                        DepName = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Department")
                        If (TargetPanel.Name.Contains("Wine")) Then
                            ReportLabel(Counter + 12).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        Else
                            ReportLabel(Counter).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        End If

                    Case ReportMode.Week
                        DataValue = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Week")
                        DepName = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Department")
                        If (TargetPanel.Name.Contains("Wine")) Then
                            ReportLabel(Counter + 12).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        Else
                            ReportLabel(Counter).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        End If

                    Case ReportMode.Month
                        DataValue = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Month")
                        DepName = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Department")
                        If (TargetPanel.Name.Contains("Wine")) Then
                            ReportLabel(Counter + 12).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        Else
                            ReportLabel(Counter).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        End If

                    Case ReportMode.Year
                        DataValue = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Year")
                        DepName = FoundRows(Counter).Item("Department")
                        If (TargetPanel.Name.Contains("Wine")) Then
                            ReportLabel(Counter + 12).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        Else
                            ReportLabel(Counter).Text = GetLabelData(DepName, DataValue)
                        End If

                End Select

                If (MaxDataValue > 0) Then
                    'Set column height to a scale of the maximum value
                    ColHeight = (DataValue * GraphHeight) / MaxDataValue
                End If

                'Set colours
                PenWWC.Color = Colors(Counter + 2)
                BrushWWC = New SolidBrush(Colors(Counter + 2))

                'Draw and fill
                DrawColumn(Dep_Graph, GraphXOrigin, TargetPanel.Height - ColHeight - Offset, ColWidth, ColHeight, PenWWC, BrushWWC)

                'Reset X0 to the next point
                GraphXOrigin = GraphXOrigin + ColWidth + Gap

            Next

        End With

        GraphXOrigin = Gap

        Dep_Graph.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

As can be seen in the video I have included a message box at the point where I clear the graphing area to show that this is NOT what is happening.

As I say, up until recently the form displayed with graphs showing; no changes have been made to this section of the application code so i don't know what is happening.
Further, as shown in the video, if I select the date for which the form is set, the graphs appear and if I change date, the new graphs appear, without problem.

Any suggestions most welcome. AFAIK I have posted all the relevant code here.

TIA,

Dermot

Comment: Remove this line: `Dim Dep_Graph As Graphics = TargetPanel.CreateGraphics` and start over, this time using only the `Paint` event of your Controls to draw what you need to draw. The Graphics object provided by `PaintEventArgs` is what you need.

Comment: @Jimi: If that answers the question, you should post it as an answer.